# Order a List a specific way

Tags: c#, list

I have a problem. I have a list with 4 coins and 4 values. Now the List is sorted by name like this:

```
 1. BTC---Value
 2. ETH---Value
 3. LTC---Value
 4. USDT---Value
```

But now I want to get a List with only 2 coins left:
The last coin needs to be USDT and the first Coin is the coin with the highest value. So for example if all the coins have value 3 and BTC has value 4, then I want a List like this:

```
 1. BTC---Value
 2. USDT---Value
```

How can I do that, because I know how to sort by value, but not with all my preferences....

Can someone help me?

**DETAILS**

Even if USDT has the highest value, I want that coin at the last place. If you add another coin, it needs to just look at the highest value again (except for USDT) and place that coin at the top with USDT on second place!

Comment: What is the *value* of the coin? Why 1st coin - `BTC---Value` is of the highest value? What if I add `5. RUB---Value`?

Comment: A [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results would be super helpful.

Comment: Not sure what you want in the scenario USDT is the highest value, but simply remove the USDT value from the list, stick it into a variable, sort the list, create a new list with the top value from the original list, and append the USDT value to the new list.

Comment: not the most efficient but this works - `var sorted = coins.OrderByDescending(s => s.ValueOfCoin).Take(1).Append(coins.First(s => s.Name == "USDT")).ToList();` - will not work as expected if the list only has "USDT" in it - (https://dotnetfiddle.net/olF5Zm)

Comment: How many elements should be in the results if USDT is not present? Can USDT be present in the input list twice?

Comment: What should happen if the input list has only one item? What if that one item is USDT? What if the input has zero items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated code based on comment by DubDub.

```
 var intermediate =  list.OrderBy(x=> x.Name=="USDT").ThenByDescending(x=>x.Value);
 var result = new []{intermediate.First(),intermediate.Last()};
```

Example,
**Scenario 1 : When there are more than 2 items**

```
 var list = new List<Coin>
 {
    new Coin{Name="USDT", Value = 29},
    new Coin{Name="ETH", Value = 13},
    new Coin{Name="LTC", Value = 21},
    new Coin{Name="BTC", Value = 3},
 };
```

Output

[image]

**Scenario 2 : When there are only two items**

```
 var list = new List<Coin>
 {
    new Coin{Name="USDT", Value = 29},
    new Coin{Name="LTC", Value = 21},
 };
```

[image]

Comment: Close, but he only wants the final list to have two coins and that's it.

Comment: @DubDub aha...didnt notice that.

Comment: @DubDub Have updated the answer to filter the first and last elements

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Linq. This wouldn't modify the list; it would create a new enumerable sorted by your criteria.

```
var sortedCoins = coins.OrderBy(c => c.Name == "USDT")
                       .ThenByDescending(c => c.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Coin> coins = new List<Coin>()
        {
            new Coin ("BTC", 1),
            new Coin ("ETH", 2),
            new Coin ("LTC", 3),
            new Coin ("USDT", 4),
        };

        Coin usdt = coins.First(x => x.Name == "USDT");

        coins.Remove(usdt);

        coins = new List<Coin>() { coins.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First(), usdt };
    }
}

public class Coin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public Coin(string name, double value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following stolen class from a previous answer that is now gone so I'm not sure who to give credit to, but you should be able to do the following.

**Coin class**

```
public class Coin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Actual code to handle list**

```
List<Coin> list = new List<Coin>
{
    new Coin{Name="USDT", Value = 29},
    new Coin{Name="ETH", Value = 13},
    new Coin{Name="LTC", Value = 21},
    new Coin{Name="BTC", Value = 3},
};

// Take out USDT coin
Coin USDTcoin = list.Find(coin => coin.Name == "USDT");
list.RemoveAt(list.FindIndex(coin => coin.Name == "USDT"));

// Order list
list = list.OrderByDescending(coin => coin.Value).ToList();

// Make new list
list = new List<Coin>
{
    list[0],
    USDTcoin
};
```